# Does English have a version of "pouring water on a goose"?

Tags: translation, popular-refrains, proverbs, swedish

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verkan

> Det där har lika mycket verkan som att hälla vatten på en gås.
>
> That has as much effect as pouring water on a goose.

It means that something is futile or pointless; the goose doesn't care (almost at all) about having water poured over it; it just trickles off its water-resistant plumage.

Does this Swedish (?) saying have a version in English? Is it literally "pouring water on a goose"?

(In general, I find it highly frustrating to try to find English versions of such "sayings". In many cases, they don't seem to exist at all, or if they do, it's impossible to find by searching and you have to ask.)

Comment: You can say *water off a duck's back* as far as taking things in stride. Or *like bringing coals to Newcastle* to mean fruitless.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as @Yosef Baskin has said in a comment, this translates perfectly from goose to duck in the phrase **like water off a duck's back**.

> **(like) water off a duck's back** 
> informal : having no effect on someone 
> He
> tried to convince her to take the job, but his advice was like water
> off a duck's back.
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%28like%29%20water%20off%20a%20duck%27s%20back)

This tangible metaphor and/or simile shows how one can be unaffected or impervious to an event, like the idea behind outcome independence.  The ducks, like the geese, do not let the water stick; they take it as it comes and keep on going.

Pouring water on a duck to as useless as [a chocolate teapot](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104958/origin-of-as-useful-as-a-chocolate-teapot-fireguard) or to keep with the aquatic theme, a [fish with a bicycle](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/a-woman-needs-a-man-like-a-fish-needs-a-bicycle.html); it's pointless.

> Dunn's modesty is appropriate, as 'A needs a B like a C needs a D' was
> a well-established format in the USA many years before 1970; for
> example, this usage in the Connecticut newspaper The Hartford Courant,
> December, 1898:
>
> The place [Aragon, Spain] didn't need an American consul any more than
> a cow needs a bicycle; for it had no trade with America, and no
> American tourist ever dreamed of stopping there.
>
> Or this, from The Detroit Free Press, October, 1906:
>
> The house didn't need a fire then any more than a horse needs a shave.

Answer (score 0):

Different localities have their own phrases that match this, but some more "universal" English ones I can think of are:

- "A wild-goose chase"
- "Pissing/spitting into the wind"
- "A fool's errand"

Also the following might fit similar situations:

- "As useful as a chocolate teapot" (refering to a useless object)
- "Like hearding cats" (a task so difficult it's pointless)
- "Getting blood from a stone" (sometimes used to describe the futility of getting information out of someone)

Comment: I don't think "Pissing into the wind" is equivalent. The point about that is that the action rebounds on you. It is used to express futility but there's always the connotation of negative consequences in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the equivalent is actually "whistling into the wind."  Futile because no one can hear you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).